# Symfony2 assetic bundle Issue

Tags: php, css, assetic, symfony-2.7

config.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ FrontendBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
    sass: /usr/bin/sass
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/../../web/
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../../web/
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scss:
            style: 'expanded'
            compass: true
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
        compass:
            bin: /usr/bin/compass
            images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../../src/FrontendBundle/Resources/assets/images
            generated_images_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../../src/FrontendBundle/Resources/public/images/sprites
            http_generated_images_path: /images/sprites
```

Template:

```
<?php foreach ($view['assetic']->stylesheets(
  array('@FrontendBundle/Resources/assets/scss/homepage.scss'),
  array('compass'),
  array('output' => 'css/homepage.css')
) as $url):
  $styles[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. $view->escape($url) .' " />' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Prod environment works just fine. css/homepage.css is generated, and there is link to it in result html.

Problems are with dev environment. If I try to generate css dynamically i get "Unable to generate a URL for the named route..." error, with "bundles" option set in config_dev.yml and assetic routes in roting_dev.yml. This is only solutions I found for this issue, none of them worked.

If I try to do prod-like, with setting "use_controller" to false, in result html I get link to "homepage_homepage_1.css" instead of "homepage.css", which is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new [Asset component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component#configuration-changes) for **Symfony 2.7**?

<kbd>**app/config/config.yml**</kbd>

```
framework:
    assets:
        version: 'v5'
        version_format: '%%s?version=%%s'
        base_path: ~
        base_urls: ['http://cdn.example.com', 'https://secure.example.com']
        packages:
           scss:
               base_path: bundles/mybundle/scss
           compass:
               base_path: bundles/mybundle/compass
```

Then you should recall the correct stylesheet with something like that:

```
{{ asset('myscss.css', 'scss') }}
{# /bundles/mybundle/scss/myscss.css #}

{{ asset('mycompass.css', 'compass') }}
{# /bundles/mybundle/compass/mycompass.css #}
```

I suggest you to use Twig on your views so you could filter your variables [through an if statement](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons)  (like `assetic`).